# can format and partition sd card but cannot see device entries

Tags: filesystems, partition, sd-card

I have a microSD card (4 GB) that I can format with `dd` and `fdisk`. I have created two partitions and when writing the partition table. I get a warning about ioctl advising to run partprobe.

Running `partprobe` does not complain anymore, but I can't see the partition entries with `ls /dev/` although `fdisk -l` shows them.

Also, taking the card off and putting it again does the same (no entries, `fdisk` shows the partitions). I don't think the card is corrupted as I can format it and use it normally in both Windows and Linux.

I'm thinking it's because of some hardware interference with the USB converter I'm using. Has anybody faced this kind of issue?

Comment: Have you checked `ls -l /dev/block`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the reason... because I was on a VM and the SD card was on a USB adaptor, I needed to connect to the VM the USB converter device, as well as the SD card itself. Now, it works fine